# SQL - how to find unique values from 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite, having

I'm using SQLite, and would like to get only rows with values that are unique per table. I know how to get values per each column, but can not create a single (sqlite compatible) select to get unique value from both column.

Here is data example:

| col_A | col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 777 |
| 222 | 333 |
| 222 | 111 |
| 444 | 333 |
| 222 | 555 |
| 333 | 666 |
| 333 | 777 |

My desired result from above example would be rows with unique values that include only: ***444, 555, 666.***

| col_A | col_B |
| --- | --- |
| **444** | 333 |
| 222 | **555** |
| 333 | **666** |

222 should not be in results as it appears multiple times in col_A.
777 should not be in results as it appears multiple times in col_B.
I need only single occurrence of value in either col_A or col_B. Unique value per table, not column.

How far i managed to get:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE 
        (SELECT col_A as asset from my_table GROUP BY col_A HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
         UNION
        SELECT col_B as asset from my_table GROUP BY col_B HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
            IN (col_A, col_B)
```

I have tried with UNION and few other approaches, but can not achieve desired result.

Comment: What about the value `111`? It is unique in both columns. What if columns have a different number of unique values?

Comment: You wrote `222 should not be in results as it appears multiple times in col_A`, and yet it ***is*** included in your results.

Comment: @MatBailie, yes 222 is present in my example result as one of the values because of the full row select. Your answer is the best, as it is noticeably faster than others. I bolded values in example result as they are important  and result depends on them. Non-bolded values in example results are just there because of full row select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  symetric AS
(
  SELECT col_a, col_b, col_a AS lookup FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col_a, col_b, col_b AS lookup FROM t
)
SELECT
  col_a, col_b
FROM
  symetric   AS t
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
      FROM symetric
     WHERE lookup          = t.lookup
       AND (col_a, col_b) <> (t.col_a, t.col_b)
  )
ORDER BY
  col_a, col_b
```

Demo ; https://dbfiddle.uk/9tzUASle

Comment: Thanks. This is currently fastest solution for my problem. As mentioned under my (OP) post, I need all/multiple columns in real solution when returning result. So i modified your solution to get full row select of all 10+ attributes.

Comment: @AndroidTank For best results you'll benefit from an id column, and make sure to have indexes on (col_a, id) (col_b, id), ... , (col_j, id), as highlighted in the demo.

Answer (score 5):

To Start filtering by `UNION ALL` considering the keyword ***either***
would be suitable option along with `HAVING` clause to determine the distinct values such as

```
WITH t1 AS  
(
 SELECT col
   FROM (SELECT col_A AS col  FROM t UNION ALL
         SELECT col_B         FROM t) AS tt
  GROUP BY col
 HAVING COUNT(*)=1 
)
SELECT t.* 
  FROM t1
  JOIN t
    ON col IN ( col_A , col_B )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hojmW3vJ)</kbd>

Comment: Depending on table size, the last join predicate may be quite slow (requiring a scan). It may be better to UNION two queries, one joining on column A, one joining on column B, as then indexes can be used for seeks, if each column is indexed independently.

Comment: Wanted to mark this answer as accepted until better one appeared. As mentioned in comment above your solution is slower on higher row count. First run takes 700-800ms on 2000 rows. Mat's solution does it in 150ms.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a query like this:

```
;with unqs as (
  select col_c
  from (
    select col_c, count(col_c) cnt
    from (
      select col_A as col_c
      from my_table
      union all
      select col_B as col_c
      from my_table) as t
     group by col_c) as tt
  where cnt = 1
)
select *
from my_table
where col_A in (select col_c from unqs)
   or col_B in (select col_c from unqs);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/46fc8/5)